# How to grab everything before a 3rd occurrence of a character in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I grab all the data before the 3rd '-'? 
Below I have the sample data:

```
000700-      - - 8  
015111-      - 005 -  
019999-      - 005 -  
A01- 01200-   0 - 5  
A01-012000- - 5  
A02-015450- - 5  
A02-015450- 003 - 1  
D08-020700- - 8  
D08-020710- - 5  
D08-020710- 013 - 1  
D08-020710- 013 - 3
```

This is what I have done and I get the proper info. but because there is some spaces missing being removed I cannot do a proper comparison to get the data in Crystal Reports.

```
reverse(substring(reverse(a.ProjectionCode),
        charindex('-', re‌​verse(a.ProjectionCo‌​de)) + 1, 
        len(reverse(a.ProjectionCode))))) as PhaseCode
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this? Is it actually "isqlquery"?

Comment: no sorry i wanted to tag sqlquery

Comment: Are there always only 3 dashes?

Comment: yes you are correct

Comment: this is what i have done and i get the proper info. but because there is some spaces missing being removed i cannot do a proper comparison to get the data in crystal reports.  reverse(substring(reverse(a.ProjectionCode),charindex('-',reverse(a.ProjectionCode))+1, len(reverse(a.ProjectionCode))))) as PhaseCode

Comment: You should update your question with the code you have tried. comments are horrible for formatting. But the code you posted there is invalid anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need and will work even in the event that there are more or less than 3 dashes for a given row.

```
-- Test Data...
INSERT #TestData (SomeString) VALUES 
    ('000700- - - 8'),
    ('015111- - 005 -'),
    ('019999- - 005 -'),
    ('A01- 01200- 0 - 5'),
    ('A01-012000- - 5'),
    ('A02-015450- - 5'),
    ('A02-015450- 003 - 1'),
    ('D08-020700- - 8'),
    ('D08-020710- - 5'),
    ('D08-020710- 013 - 1'),
    ('D08-020710- 013 - 3'),
    ('1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9'),  -- More than 3 dashes
    ('zaq12wsx-vfr445tgb'), -- lesst than 3 dashes
    ('987654321345678');    -- No dashes

-- Query...
SELECT 
    td.SomeString,
    LEFT(td.SomeString, ISNULL(d3.Dash, LEN(td.SomeString) + 1)- 1)
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', td.SomeString, 1), 0)) ) d1 (Dash)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', td.SomeString, d1.Dash + 1), 0)) ) d2 (Dash)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', td.SomeString, d2.Dash + 1), 0)) ) d3 (Dash);
```

EDIT: Adding function and usage code...

iTVF

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_TextLeftOfThirdDash
/* =============================================================================================
iTVF that returns all text to the left og the 3rd dash in a string of text
============================================================================================= */
(
    @String VARCHAR(8000)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    SELECT 
        StringRemain = LEFT(@String, ISNULL(d3.Dash, LEN(@String) + 1)- 1)
    FROM 
        ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', @String, 1), 0)) ) d1 (Dash)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', @String, d1.Dash + 1), 0)) ) d2 (Dash)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (NULLIF(CHARINDEX('-', @String, d2.Dash + 1), 0)) ) d3 (Dash);
GO
```

How to use the function...

```
SELECT 
    td.SomeString, 
    l3d.StringRemain
FROM
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY dbo.tfn_TextLeftOfThirdDash(td.SomeString) l3d;
```

HTH,
Jason

Comment: i will try this and let you know

Comment: this works thank you, i just have to put it part of my sql view now and test it with my crystal report. will let you know how it goes.

Comment: i need help with the view. see below i posted what i have

Comment: Answer has been updated... Suggest placing the code in an iTVF and then reference the iTVF in your view.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
declare @str varchar(200) = 'A02-015450- 003 - 1';

select SUBSTRING(@str, 1, LEN(@str) - CHARINDEX('-',  REVERSE(@str), 1));
```

Comment: it works but below is the results.   how do i remove the last '-'

Comment: '000700-      - -'   
'015111-      - 005 -'   
'A02-015450- 003 -'   
'C04-033005- -'

Comment: @user3006866 just edited it to remove the last dash.

Comment: i am using the code to create a sql view. then i am pulling the view into my crystal report to join it with another view.

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear what you expect as output here. But taking a guess you could use PARSENAME here since your data is always exactly three dashes. Please realize that if you have any periods in your data this will NOT work correctly. In a perfect world this data would not be delimited in a single column like this. It should be spread across columns. What you have here is violating 1NF.

```
declare @Something table
(
    SomeValue varchar(50)
)

insert @Something
values
('000700- - - 8')
,('015111- - 005 -')
,('019999- - 005 -')
,('A01- 01200- 0 - 5')
,('A01-012000- - 5')
,('A02-015450- - 5')
,('A02-015450- 003 - 1')
,('D08-020700- - 8')
,('D08-020710- - 5')
,('D08-020710- 013 - 1')
,('D08-020710- 013 - 3 ')

select *
    , parsename(replace(SomeValue, '-', '.'), 2)
from @Something
```

Answer (score 0):

The tsql function for searching a string, charindex, accepts an argument for where to start. This start position can be calculated using another call to charindex..

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(col, 1,
    CHARINDEX('-', col,
      CHARINDEX('-', col,
        CHARINDEX('-', col)+1
      )+1
    )-1
  )
FROM table
```

Comment: this also works. thank you. i will also include this in a different sql view and see which works best with my crystal report.

Comment: I always found crystal reports a pain in the arse when giving it an SQL to get the report data itself. The strategy I eventually adopted was to download the data into my program (c#) and then give the data to the crystal report as a DataTable object..

Comment: would you be able to tell me how you downloaded the data using c#?

Comment: If, now you're testing my memory- if you google for `data walkthroughs creating a simple data application` you'll find a set of tutorials on msdn that describe accessing a database via a visual designer on visual studio. It makes things easier to the point that just a single line can connect to the database and retrieve your report data into a local object, example code `var mytable = new ReportTableAdapter().GetBlahReport()`. After this, it's a case of passing that data table to the crystal reports container. I don't recall the exact code but it was less than 10 lines ..

Comment: Take a look at posts like : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041369/set-datatable-as-datasource-for-crystal-report - there should be a few examples out there if how to pass datatablea to cr.. I recall now the reason why I downloaded the data myself was because it was a nightmare trying to get cr to use sql queries that had parameters, or were over a certain length /complexity. Some of my queries ran to well over 50 pages of a4 when printed. The app that used CR was a sort of "user chooses report parameters and runs report" type thing. Might even have the source somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has nothing natively to determine the nth position of a character or string.  My method is to create my own.  Something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[nthOccurencePos](@input VARCHAR(128), @delimiter CHAR(1), @nth INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT;
    WITH cteExample AS
    (
        --Find the index of the first delimiter
        SELECT 1 AS rowCounter, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input, 1) delPos
        UNION ALL
        --Move over one character and find the index of the next delimiter
        SELECT rowCounter + 1, CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @input, delPos + 1) 
        FROM cteExample
        WHERE delPos > 0 --When you come up empty, stop
    )
    SELECT @result = delPos FROM cteExample WHERE rowCounter = @nth;
    RETURN @result;
END
```

Now use this function to get everything before the 3rd hyphen like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(sample VARCHAR(128))

INSERT @tbl VALUES
('000700- - - 8')
,('015111- - 005 -')
,('019999- - 005 -')
,('A01- 01200- 0 - 5')
,('A01-012000- - 5')
,('A02-015450- - 5')
,('A02-015450- 003 - 1')
,('D08-020700- - 8')
,('D08-020710- - 5')
,('D08-020710- 013 - 1')
,('D08-020710- 013 - 3 ');


SELECT LEFT(sample, dbo.nthOccurencePos(sample, '-', 3) - 1) BeforeHyphen3
FROM @tbl;
```

Although you don't use this in your case, it is more common to need the nth column of data within a delimited string.  For example:

```
DECLARE @delim NVARCHAR(128);
SET @delim = 'abcdefg-hijklmnop-qrstuv-wxyz';
SELECT SUBSTRING(@delim, dbo.nthOccurencePos(@delim, '-', 2) + 1, dbo.nthOccurencePos(@delim, '-', 3) - dbo.nthOccurencePos(@delim, '-', 2) - 1) as thirdColumn
```